# webgl rotate camera around X-axis

Tags: opengl-es, camera, rotation, webgl, opengl-es-2.0

I'm having some trouble with rotating camera around X-axis. I have an image placed in the camera's scene and when I look up with camera I want to keep an image inside the scene.

First I built up some functions to create matrices:

```
mat4 makeTranslation(float tx, float ty, float tz) {
    return mat4(
         1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,
         tx, ty, tz, 1.
    );
}
mat4 makeXRotation(float angleInDegrees) {
    float angleInRadians = angleInDegrees * M_PI / 180.;
    float c = cos(angleInRadians);
    float s = sin(angleInRadians);

    return mat4(
        1., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., c, s, 0.,
        0., -s, c, 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 1.
    );
}
mat4 makeZRotation(float angleInDegrees) {
    float angleInRadians = angleInDegrees * M_PI / 180.;
    float c = cos(angleInRadians);
    float s = sin(angleInRadians);
    return mat4(
         c, s, 0., 0.,
        -s, c, 0., 0.,
         0., 0., 1., 0.,
         0., 0., 0., 1.
    );
}
// camera
mat4 myW2N(float ax, float ay, float zNear, float zFar) {
    float cx = 1.0 / ax;
    float cy = 1.0 / ay;
    float z0 = -zNear;
    float z1 = -zFar;
    float az = (z0 + z1) / (z0 - z1);
    float bz = (1. - az) * z0;
    return mat4(
        cx, 0., 0., 0.,
        0., cy, 0., 0.,
        0., 0., az, bz,
        0., 0., -1., 0.
    );
}
// transpose
mat3 rotationW2R() {
    return mat3(
        0., 0., 1.,
        1., 0., 0.,
        0., 1., 0.
    );
}
```

Than just **translated camera position** in Y-axis

```
float ax = tan(hFOV * M_PI);
float ay = ax / aspectRatio;
mat4 res = makeTranslation(0., move_y, 0.) * myW2N(ax,ay,6.,2.);
```

But I don't want to translate camera position I want to **rotate it around axis** and keep image inside the scene

And this is how I'm trying to do it:

```
float ax = tan(hFOV * M_PI);
float ay = ax / aspectRatio;
mat4 res = makeXRotation(pitch) * makeZRotation(roll) * makeTranslation(0., move_y, 0.) * myW2N(ax,ay,6.,2.);
```

But in the end my image doesn't move up it expands on both sides up and down not just up or just down, and to expand it vertically I need to rotate camera around X-axis, when I rotate it around Y-axis it expands horizontally.

Don't you have any advice how to fix it?

Comment: So is what you want billboards? A quad that always faces the camera?

Comment: @WacławJasper Not sure what you mean by billboards but yes, I want a quad that always faces the camera, where ever the camera scene moves I want to move there my image too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Billboard is the common name for a quad that always faces the camera.

The billboard mesh data is a plane that faces the camera (z = 0).

You can render a billboard by setting the rotation portion of the model view matrix to 0, only leaving the translation part: `gl_Position = projection * zeroRotationAndScaling(view * model) * attr_position;` in the vertex shader.

If you google around searching for "billboard" Im sure you will find lots of references like [this](http://nehe.gamedev.net/article/billboarding_how_to/18011/).

Comment: I thought it's a fragment shader problem. Anyway, I'll try today and then I'll let you know, thank you for reply!

Comment: Another question, if I compute gl_Position this way will I affect all content of my 3D world? Because I want to apply "billboard" behaviour only on my image and keep panorama image without any changes. You can see on my images above.

Comment: Yep. Either use a different shader for billboard or pass in a model matrix such that `view * matrix ==  zeroRotationAndScaling(view * model)`.